# Meaning of "pitching" in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, synonyms

In episode 9 of *The Wonder Years*, it's Christmas time. The children are sulking because their father didn't want to buy them a color TV. It has not been a good day for the family. Only Norma is not boring (or seems so). In some point, the narrator says:

> NARRATOR: That night, all the seams were showing. Only Mom [Norma] was in there
>   **pitching** like a lone fireman at a five-alarm blaze.
>
> NORMA: Eggnog, anyone? Lydia Herschmuller just called. To remind us
>   about the carolling party tonight. I told her we’d be there with bells
>   on!

I guess the narrator wanted to show that Norma was being resilient and was trying to cheer them up. But I couldn't find a appropriate synonymous for "pitching" in the sentence above. Could someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your English dictionary provides several meanings for the verb _pitch_. Did none of them seem appropriate? When you say you couldn't find a synonym, what do you mean? Sometimes, dictionaries don't provide an _exact_ example of the usage you are looking for, and then you have to think about all the meanings and examples.

Comment: Well, in fact, I have been using at least 4 online dictionaries. But the one you use to answer seems to be more thorough than at least 3 of them. Could you mention it, please?

Comment: Andrew uses Merriam-Webster in his answer below, but a good starting point is the **[OneLook](http://OneLook.com)** aggregator. This provides links to a score of dictionaries on one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this definition:

> [**to pitch**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pitch) (transitive verb): (3)
>   a :  *to present or advertise especially in a high-pressure way :  plug, promote*
>   b :  *to attempt to persuade especially with a sales pitch*

and this:

> [**to pitch in**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pitch%20in) (intransitive verb): (2)  *to contribute to a common endeavor*

Your example is kind of a mix of both of these definitions.  The mother is trying to *pitch* the idea that the family should be celebrating, and she is also *pitching in* to the effort to cheer them up, with great (but possibly futile) enthusiasm.

Side note:  A "five-alarm blaze" is a scale of the severity of a fire, from one to five, with five being the worst.  I don't know if modern fire companies still use this scale, but the analogy implies that a lone fireman has little hope of putting out this large a fire (but she's still trying).